# Enable experimental features in Android Chrome WebView - Aim: CSS Regions support for WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to enable Chrome Experimental Features in the new Android Chrome WebView like you can do in Chrome Browser (chrome://flags) ... I'm researching this because i'm searching for a way to get **CSS Regions** support in a WebView. Any other suggestion to get CSS Regions support is very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2017 (WebView version 57), this is officially not supported on retails builds. See this thread of the Android WebView Beta Channel, where the moderator says it is deliberately not supported -

https://plus.google.com/100644560102269275105/posts/hDq6iCHiZ1o

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid this is not possible.