# Cordova - how to modify webview flags?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, crosswalk

I want to ask about flags that are available in the normal Chrome browser (chrome://flags). Previously I was using Crosswalk with Cordova and I had the option to change stuff in config.xml by adding the preference `xwalkCommandLine`.

```
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--enable-experimental-canvas-features --ignore-gpu-blacklist" />
```

Since Crosswalk is basically dead, is it possible to do the same thing in Cordova? Are there other preference names (or maybe even plugins) that will enable this feature?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible in the underlying Chrome WebView that Cordova is using.  Experimental features are purposely inaccessible in the WebView API that Android apps use.  See the answer below about why this is not supported:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798884