# chrome 80 samesite cookies default change - android webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, android-webview, samesite

A significant change is coming in the chrome browser(version 80.x), and I wonder how you can test it on Android `webview`.
On the web, you just need to set a couple of defaults for flags via chrome: flags (in the browser) -

- SameSite by default cookies - need to change to enable.
- Cookies without SameSite must be secure - also need to set to enable.

This way you simulate the behavior of the browser when this new release kicks in.

---

- My question is how do you test it in advance on Android `webviews`?
- How can you change flags in the internal browser used by the webview (Android System Webview?)

---

Basically what I'm asking - How can I test this on Android webview right now so I know I'm not affected when the change happens?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how do you test it in advance on Android webviews?

In order to test webview updates for your mobile application :

1. Each Android developer can install the beta webview (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview.beta&hl=en) on device
2. Developers can then set their device to use the beta webview implementation through Developer Tools (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#chrome-+-webview,-together)
3. Then finally, developers and QA can run their webview-based application on the device, verifying the webview version through chrome://inspect (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

> How can you change flags in the internal browser used by the webview (Android System Webview?)

For change flags option similar to Chrome browser, this is not supported it seems based on this thread: [Enable experimental features in Android Chrome WebView - Aim: CSS Regions support for WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994625/enable-experimental-features-in-android-chrome-webview-aim-css-regions-suppor/43798884#43798884)

> How can I test this on Android webview right now so I know I'm not affected when the change happens?

Not your question, but related: Android webviews are not in scope for the coming Chrome Browser 80 update in February 2020 related to samesite cookies. There is no schedule yet for Android webviews (See "*Q: Are cookies in WebViews affected by the new default behavior?*" in https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/updates/same-site/faq), but you can monitor the chrome blog for announcements (https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/search/label/Android%20WebView).

After an announcement and an accompanying Beta Android System Webview released, developers can follow the steps listed above.

Comment: Even though it is not enforced, it is mentioned that,

The new SameSite behavior will not be enforced on Android Webview until later, though app developers are advised to declare the appropriate SameSite cookie settings for Android WebViews based on versions of Chrome that are compatible with the None value. So it is good to implement.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/commandline-flags.md#applying-features-with-flags

You can use that to enable SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure.

Edit: My apologies, I missed a crucical detail. You can toggle the flags on as stated above, but that won't actually do anything because WebView is currently [hard-coded](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/browser/cookie_manager.cc?q=cookie_manager.cc&ss=chromium&l=334-338) to use the legacy behavior in all circumstances. This overrides the flag settings, so you can't get the new behavior in Android WebView at the moment. That said, the new behavior will be the same as in Chrome Browser, so you can test the site in Chrome Browser for now and it will be basically the same (the only exception is the CookieManager WebView API, which does not exist on Chrome Browser).